# Moving a Control horizontally

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, controls, storyboard

I have a list of buttons wrapped inside a stackpanel which stacks them horizontly. I want to know the code behind in C# to apply an animation such that if my mouse is near the left end of the MainWindow, the buttons slowly moves right. Whereas if my mouse is near the right side of the MainWindow, the buttons slowly moves left.

The buttons are added and styled at runtime.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use a Mouse Event on the window to capture the position. Then you can scroll if the mouse is where you want.

Comment: yes i can do all that. Just gimme a snippet on how to use Storyboard to move a control horizontly to the right non stop

Comment: Is it acceptable to move the stackpanel itself?  What is the stackpanel contained in?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to use a `canvas` instead of the `stackpanel` you can use this code to achieve the animation I wrote for you right away:

Declare a field in you class like the following: `private bool _running = true;`

After this you can use this to animate your buttons.

```
new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (_running)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(20);

                    canvas.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
                    {
                        var position = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas).X;
                        var canvasWidth = canvas.ActualWidth;

                        if (position >=0 && position < 10.0d)
                            btn.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)btn.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) + 1);

                        if (position <= canvasWidth && position > canvasWidth - 10.0d)
                            btn.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)btn.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) - 1);
                    }));
                }
            }).Start();
```

Dont forget to add following usages to your class:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

If you want the code to work with more than just one buttons just use a list for example and rewrite the code a little bit. Also adjust `Thread.Sleep(20)` to your needs.

Good luck.